# Bambora in how to payment work in for testing PHP

Tags: php, api, bambora

Can you about me how to apply test **API PHP**  payment deduction in **Bambora** . i try to this following step and result give me this can you about me where is my mistake.

```
$merchant_id = Config('bamboraConfig.bambora.merchant_id');
        $api_key = Config('bamboraConfig.bambora.api_key');
        $api_version = Config('bamboraConfig.bambora.api_version');
        $platform = Config('bamboraConfig.bambora.platform');
        // dd($request->all());
        $this->validate($request,[
         'name'=>'required',
         'email_address'=>'required',
         'phone_number'=>'required',
         'address_line1'=>'required',
         'city'=>'required',
         'province'=>'required',
         'postal_code'=>'required',
         'country'=>'required'
        ]);
        $beanstream = new \Beanstream\Gateway($merchant_id, $api_key, $platform, $api_version);
        $complete = TRUE; //set to FALSE for PA

        $profile_data = array(
                        'billing' => array(
                            'name' => $request->name,
                            'email_address' => $request->email_address,
                            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
                            'address_line1' => $request->address_line1,
                            'city' => $request->city,
                            'province' => $request->province,
                            'postal_code' => $request->postal_code,
                            'country' => $request->country
                        )
            );
            $payment_data = array(
                    'order_number' => '23423',
                    'amount' => 254,
                    'payment_method' => 'card',
                    'card' => array(
                        'name' => 'Mr. Card Testerson',
                        'number' => '371100001000131',
                        'expiry_month' => '07',
                        'expiry_year' => '22',
                        'cvd' => '1234'
                    ),
                    'billing' => array(
                        'name' => $request->name,
                        'email_address' => $request->email_address,
                        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
                        'address_line1' => $request->address_line1,
                        'city' => $request->city,
                        'province' => $request->province,
                        'postal_code' => $request->postal_code,
                        'country' => $request->country
                    ),
                    'shipping' => array(
                        'name' => $request->name,
                        'email_address' => $request->email_address,
                        'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
                        'address_line1' => $request->address_line1,
                        'city' => $request->city,
                        'province' => $request->province,
                        'postal_code' => $request->postal_code,
                        'country' => $request->country
                    )
        );

        $makeCardPayment = $beanstream->payments()->makeCardPayment($payment_data, $complete);
        return $makeCardPayment;
```

and result show me this when code executed  then -

```
 [4] => Array
        (
            [code] => 0
            [category] => 2
            [message] => CALL HELP DESK
            [reference] => 
        )
```

can't get where is my mistake can you help me to find out this problem solution .
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: hi, is there a dev key for test mode?

Comment: @jspcal yes i use dev key for test mode